Pass function to the label argument in gtsummary
I often find myself changing the labels of a gtsummary object post function:
library(gtsummary)
table1 <- trial %>%
  tbl_summary()    

I change the labels of the gtsummary object table1 "manually"
table1[["table_body"]][["label"]] <- 
  table1[["table_body"]][["label"]] %>% 
  str_to_title()

I have made this part into a function:
clean_tbl_labels <- function(tbl) {
  tbl[["table_body"]][["label"]] <- 
    tbl[["table_body"]][["label"]] %>% 
    gsub("_", " ", .) %>% 
    str_to_title()
  tbl
}

but there must be an easier way to do this?
I am thinking of something along the lines:
table1 <- 
  trial %>%
  tbl_summary(., label = list(.x ~ str_to_title())


Do you mean to be using the tbl_summary function from the gtsummary package?

Yes, bad morning. Adjusted in post. Thanks.

You can use the modify_table_body helper function:
trial %>%
  select(age, grade, response) %>%
  tbl_summary() |>
  modify_table_body(~ .x %>% 
        dplyr::mutate(label=str_to_title(label)))



I guess the only draw back with this (as is with my other function) is that it takes all the labels. So now the tumour grade, previously "III", is now "Iii". I wonder what could improve this without writing too much code?

You can also define a function that provides you a named list of labels you wish to use. You can then pass this function to the tbl_summary(label) argument. In the example below, I've made all labels uppercase, but you can implement any transformation you wish.
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.2'

# function returns a named list of labels to use in `tbl_summary()`
my_default_labels <- function(data) {
  purrr::imap(
    data, 
    ~ attr(.x, "label") %||% # use the column label, if available
      .y |>                  # if no label, use the column name
      toupper()              # this is where you could make you customizations
  )
}


trial |> 
  select(age, response) |> 
  tbl_summary(
    label = my_default_labels(trial)
  ) |> 
  bold_labels() |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on SO




Characteristic
N = 200




AGE
47 (38, 57)


Unknown
11


TUMOR RESPONSE
61 (32%)


Unknown
7



Created on 2024-05-07 with reprex v2.1.0
